# CKEditor: Change tag filtering from a list of 'allow' to list of 'dis-allow'

Tags: wysiwyg

I have two CKedit text filter profiles --

- Advanced
- Full HTML.

The Advanced allows a restricted set of HTML tags and the Full filters no tags.  I want to add a second profile that is allowed the Full set of tags with the sole exception of `<script>`.  I have found much documentation on allowing `<script>` but find nothing about restricting just this one.

It seems counter intuitive that the only way would be to build a list of all html tag leaving out only this one.

Comment: Which Drupal version you are using? Are you talking about `Text Formats`? Do you want to create new text format and wan to set HTML elements as  per your need?

Comment: This if for Drupal 7.  I want to have a ckeditor filter that filters out only the 'script' html tag.